# Creating menu driven program in oracle pl/sql using case statement

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, case

I am trying to create a menu driven program just like we do in c or java to take input from user and perform some operation based on the selected value using a switch case. This is what i am trying to achieve

```
DECLARE 
   choice char(1);
   radius number;
   area number(5,4);
   base number;
   height number;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('A. Area of Circle');
    dbms_output.put_line('B. Area of Triangle');
    dbms_output.put_line('C. Area of Sphere'); 
    choice :=&choice;
    case
        when choice='A' then
            radius:=&radius
            area = radius*radius*3.14;
            dbms_output.put_line('Area of circle is : ' || area);
        when choice = 'B' then 
            base:=&base;
            height:=&height;
            area=0.5*base*height;
            dbms_output.put_line('Area of Triangle is : ' || area);
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Choice');
    end case;
END; 
/
```

But the problem is it doesn't even output the first 3 lines and directly jump to the `choice:=&choice` statement.Also the case is not working.

Comment: We don't write  an interactive user-input driven program in PL/SQL. It does not work by using &. Better use SQL* plus features like `prompt`

Comment: Although I doubt you could achieve something that you are trying using `prompt`

Comment: @KaushikNayak `It does not work by using &` - It works. `&` is a substitution variable and it works in anonymous block. Not sure what you wanted to convey when you made this statement. Try executing the below block and see if it works or not. Read a good article here https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915518

Comment: @XING and Rahul : What I meant was,for this example,  If  the user enters the choice 'B' , it will still prompt for `radius`. Which shouldn't be the case. You expect it to prompt for base and height, which it does not. So this back and forth information flow can't happen with & as It is not sequential.

Comment: @KaushikNayak it would be a great help if you could show me an example of using the prompt feature to achieve the desired functionality